# Which type should I use to store an ID card in database?

Tags: database

What is the best way to store an ID card number (8 digits) in a database? Integer or VARCHAR(8)? Thanks. I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Why not `CHAR(8)` as an option? Are they not always 8 digits? And do these digits include leading zeroes or start after 9999999? And what probability is there that the format might change to alpha numeric at some point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I will assume MySQL for this question, as you failed to state any details.*

Since it's a numeric value, not a string, I recommend using [a numeric type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html). You can make the best use of space by using the narrowest type that's wide enough in MySQL, which is `DECIMAL(8)`.

Also make the column `UNSIGNED`, and possibly use `ZEROFILL`.

Answer (score 0):

Unsigned Integer should be large enough to handle 99999999 since it's max value is [4294967295](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html).  Integer should also be faster when searching and will also be a smaller storage data type.